# How to structure a Bill of Materials that has multiple options

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I am stuck trying to develop a Bill of Materials in Access.  I have a table call IM_Item_Registry where I have the Item_Code and a boolean for if it's a component.  Where I'm stuck is that past sins of the company made several part numbers for the same ingredient from different vendors.   A product may use ingredient 1 at the beginning of the run and ingredient 2 at the end of a run depending on inventory and it may switch from job to job (Lack of discipline and random purchasing based on price).  It's creating a headache for me because they typically have different inclusions.  How would I go about adding in the flexibility to use both? or would it just be easier to make multiple versions and then select those version upon scheduling?

I know this is loaded and I can include more detail if needed but I appreciate your help I've been researching on how to do this for a couple weeks now.

EDIT (3/28/2019)
this is for an injection molding company.

IM_Item_Registry (Fields: Item_Code, Category(Raw, manufactured, customer supplied, assembly component), Description, Component (boolean), active (boolean), Unit of Measure.

for this Bill-of-materials 100011 produces component lets call this a handle.  bill 100011 uses raw resin 700049 at 98% inclusion and raw color 600020 at 2% inclusion.  However,  we may run out of raw color 600020 and have to run it out of 600051 which would change 700049 to 98.5% inclusion because 600051 requires 1.5% inclusion to achieve the same color.

i would like to create a table that would call out for the general term lets say 600020 and 600051 is yellow color additive. then create a "ghost" number to call for either 600020 or 600051 and give both formulation recipes.  When production starts they would scan in which color they actually used to create the production BOM themselves and record which color was used and how much.  is there a way to do this in access database structuring?

I'm assuming I would need both the item_registry table, a BoM table (fields: BOM#, ParentID, Ghost_ID) and then a components table (Fields: Ghost_ID, item_code, Inclusion Rate).

Comment: You're correct that this is "loaded", and it turns out that it is also likely "Off Topic" for stackoverflow (SO).  After a review of [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), perhaps you could argue that it falls under "programming algorithms".  However, a solution likely involves too many details of overall system design to warrant a complete answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Database normalization is the guiding principle for designing efficient, useful tables and relationships in a relational database.  Access forms, subforms, reports, etc. require properly normalized tables to work as intended.  There are various levels of normalization, but the common idea is to avoid duplication of data between rows and columns of data.  Having duplicate data requires a lot of overhead in storage and in ensuring that actions on the database do not create inconsistent states (contradictory data values).  Well-normalized tables allow useful constraints to be defined between data columns and/or rows to ensure that data is valid.

The [BoM] table as proposed in the question is not normalized.  But before we get to that, the ParentID was not defined and it's not clear what it represents.  Instead, to help show why it's not normalized, let me add a [Product] column to the [BoM] table.  Then if such a handle has two alternative lists of components (ghosts?), the table would look like

```
BOMID, Product, GhostID
-----  -------  -------
1      Handle   1
1      Handle   2
```

See the duplication?  And now if the product is renamed, for instance to "Bronze Handle", then both rows need to be updated for a single conceptual element.  It also introduces the possibility of having contradictory data like

```
BOMID, Product,       GhostID
-----  -------        -------
1      Handle         1
1      Bronze Handle  2
```

---

Enough said about that, since I've already gone on too much about normalization concepts here.  Following is a basic normalized schema which would serve you better, but notice that it's not too much different that what you proposed in the question.  The only real difference is that the BoM table is normalized by splitting its columns (and purpose) into another table.

I do not list all columns here, only primary and foreign keys and a few other meaningful columns.  PK = Primary Key (unique, non-null key), FK = Foreign Key.  Proper indices should be defined on the PK and FK columns AND relationships defined with appropriate constraints.

```
Table: [IM_Item_Registry]
Item_Code (PK)

Table: [BOM]
BOMID (PK)
ProductID (FK)

Table: [BOM_Option]
OptionID (PK)
BOMID (FK)
Primary (boolean) - flags the primary/usual list of components
Description

Table: [Option_Items]
OptionID (FK; part of composite PK)
Item_Code (FK; part of composite PK)
Inclusion_Rate
```

The `[BOM].[ProductID]` column alludes to another table with details of the product which should be defined separately from the Bill of Material.  If this database really is super-simplistic, then it could just be a string field `[Product]` containing the name, but I assume there are more useful details to store.  Perhaps this is what the `ParentID` also alluded to?  (I suggest choosing names that are not so abstract like "parent" and "ghost", hence my choice of the word "option".)

Really, since `[BOM_Option]` should be limited to a single option per BOM, it would fulfill proper normalization to create another table like

```
Table: [BOM_Primary]
[BOMID] (FK and PK) - Primary key so only one primary option can be defined at once
[OptionID] (FK)
```

Comment: that was extremely helpful! I used ParentID and GhostID since most Bill of Materials are set up to have a ParentID and ChildID. ParentID is the finished product from the BoM and ChildID is the component or raw material.  But, since I was looking to do substitution methods for the ChildID I was thinking of having another table that had a GhostID (I like the idea of using OptionID as you suggested) and then having it do a calculation based on the Parent_ID Weight and the inclusion% from the Options table as you suggested.  I hope that clarifies where i was getting those field names.